# How many eight digit numbers contains all of 2,4,6,8?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I thinking about $4^3$ $*$ $9^3$ because 4 numbers has the conditon of being only 2,4,6,8 and the other 4 has 9 digit options. How do I need to approach this kind of things?

Comment: You still need to account for choosing the position of these 4 numbers.

Comment: Yeah I also tought. How do I do this?

Comment: Two things make this problem hard to answer: The first digit cannot be zero, and the same nonzero even digit could appear more than once in the eight-digit number.

Comment: Right so how its solved?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the set of $8$-digit numbers.  Let $X_i$ be the set of $8$-digit numbers who include the digit $i$ as at least one of its digits.

You ask to count $X_2\cap X_4\cap X_6\cap X_8$

To do this, let us instead look at the complementary event with respect to $X$... $\overline{X_2}\cup \overline{X_4}\cup \overline{X_6}\cup \overline{X_8}$, the set of eight-digit numbers who are missing at least one of the digits $2,4,6,8$.

We can count and expand this via the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

> $|\overline{X_2}\cup \overline{X_4}\cup \overline{X_6}\cup \overline{X_8}| = |\overline{X_2}|+|\overline{X_4}|+\dots - |\overline{X_2}\cap \overline{X_4}|-|\overline{X_2}\cap \overline{X_6}|-\dots+|\overline{X_2}\cap \overline{X_4}\cap \overline{X_6}|+\dots-|\overline{X_2}\cap \overline{X_4}\cap \overline{X_6}\cap \overline{X_8}|$

Each term in this expansion should be trivial to calculate.

> For instance, $|\overline{X_2}\cap \overline{X_4}\cap \overline{X_6}|$ are those eight-digit numbers who have none of the digits $2,4,6$.  Pick the leading digit noting it cannot be $0$ nor any of $2,4,6$.  Then pick each remaining digit noting it may not be $2,4,6$ but may be zero.  There are $6\times 7\times 7\times 7\times \cdots \times 7 = 6\times 7^7$ such possibilities.

Subtract this amount away from $|X|$ to get the amount you were interested in, those which had all of $2,4,6,8$ as opposed to those who were missing at least one of $2,4,6,8$.
Finally, recognize the symmetry of the terms to group similar terms together to simplify the final expression and reach your final conclusion.

> $9\cdot 10^7 - 4\cdot 8\cdot 9^7 + \binom{4}{2}\cdot 7\cdot 8^7 - \binom{4}{3}\cdot 6\cdot 7^7 + 5\cdot 6^7$

Comment: What makes you realize that you need to use Inclusion-Exclusion Principle here?